# Accessing a private field from within the class refuses to compile

Tags: java

This example does not compile:

```
public class Test{
    private LinkedList<Integer> lst = new LinkedList<>();

    public static Test of(int i){
        return new Test(){{
            this.lst.addFirst(i);
        }};
    }
}
```

[***DEMO***](http://ideone.com/SYMU6z)

But this does:

```
public class Test{
    private LinkedList<Integer> lst = new LinkedList<>();

    public static Test of(int i){
        Test t = new Test();
        t.lst.addFirst(i);
        return t;
    }
}
```

[***DEMO***](http://ideone.com/N7Hvbn)

Why? In both cases we access a private member from the class body.

Answer (score 5):

With the code

```
new Test() { ... }
```

you actually declare and instantiate an *anonymous subclass* of `Test`. And a subclass simply does not have access to its parent's private members.

See [JLS §15.9 (Class Instance Creation Expressions)](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.9) and [JLS §15.9.5 (Anonymous Class Declarations)](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.9.5) for more information

Answer (score 1):

When you define:

```
return new Test(){{
      this.lst.addFirst(i);
}};
```

You create an anonymous sub class of `Test`.
The access specifier of `lst` is `private`. So you may not access a `private` member of `super` class from a `sub` class. So you get compilation-error.

But when you declare:

```
Test t = new Test();
t.lst.addFirst(i);
```

You are accessing the private member `lst` from inside a method i.e. `public static Test of(int i)` of the class to which the private member belongs. So you do not get compilation-error.